# wifi not working on ubuntu 16.04 (ethernet works) - Asus x99 Mother board

Tags: 16.04, networking, wireless

I have been using ubuntu 16.04 with an ethernet connection and now need to use wifi. Unfortunately I've tried practically everything posted online as solutions to other problems with no luck.

These are the results of the network ouput shared here in order to help people debug the problem.

```
    ##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.4.0-79-generic #100-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 17 19:58:14 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, nomodeset, nouveau.modeset=0, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I218-V [8086:15a1] (rev 05)
    DeviceName:  Onboard LAN
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Ethernet Connection (2) I218-V [1043:85c4]

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8002 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:800a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 174c:3074 ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1074 SuperSpeed hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0461:4d15 Primax Electronics, Ltd Dell Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 174c:2074 ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1074 High-Speed hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1a2c:2d23 China Resource Semico Co., Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

##### lsmod #############################

eeepc_wmi              16384  0
asus_wmi               28672  1 eeepc_wmi
sparse_keymap          16384  1 asus_wmi
video                  40960  1 asus_wmi
mxm_wmi                16384  0
wmi                    20480  2 mxm_wmi,asus_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eno1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eno1' [IF1]>  
          inet addr:192.168.0.5  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::475b:5375:3dca:1d95/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8140 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6108 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:8363410 (8.3 MB)  TX bytes:772145 (772.1 KB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:fb200000-fb220000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:590 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:590 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:41486 (41.4 KB)  TX bytes:41486 (41.4 KB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

eno1      no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eno1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eno1
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eno1

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 200.42.4.203
nameserver 200.49.130.41
search fibertel.com.ar

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       973     1  0 23:51 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         eno1
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Intel Corporation
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        Ethernet Connection (2) I218-V
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         e1000e
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 3.2.6-k
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               0.1-4
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'eno1' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:19.0/net/eno1
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       eno1
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Auto Ethernet
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       407b5700-f83f-46c2-ae9a-34529936ac97
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     1000 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{1}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   407b5700-f83f-46c2-ae9a-34529936ac97 | Auto Ethernet
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.0.5/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.0.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             200.42.4.203
IP4.DNS[2]:                             200.49.130.41
IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          fibertel.com.ar
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        domain_name_servers = 200.42.4.203 200.49.130.41
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        ip_address = 192.168.0.5
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.0.1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        broadcast_address = 192.168.0.255
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       dhcp_rebinding_time = 529200
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       routers = 192.168.0.1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       dhcp_renewal_time = 302400
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       domain_name = fibertel.com.ar
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       expiry = 1498445528
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       host_name = marbel
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       network_number = 192.168.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       next_server = 192.168.0.1
DHCP4.OPTION[29]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[30]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[31]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 604800
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::475b:5375:3dca:1d95/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Wi-Fi]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Wi-Fi | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Fibertel WiFi092 5.8GHz
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires (based on set time zone)

country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (6, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (6, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 160), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 160), (6, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (6, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

eno1      no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

eno1      Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

##### module parameters #################

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac
blacklist vga16fb
blacklist nouveau
blacklist rivafb
blacklist nvidiafb
blacklist rivatv

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nouveau.conf]
blacklist nouveau
options nouveau modeset=0

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/kms-sg-blacklist.conf]
blacklist nouveau

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

[/etc/pm/config.d/config] (644 root)
SUSPEND_MODULES="iwlwifi"

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[   14.801722] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eno1: link is not ready (repeated 2 times)
[   17.869580] e1000e: eno1 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
[   17.869625] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eno1: link becomes ready
[   20.880844] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=<MAC 'eno1' [IF1]>:fe:91:14:69:c3:d7:08:00 SRC=192.168.0.1 DST=192.168.0.5 LEN=530 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=54779 DPT=36713 LEN=510 
[   20.882895] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=<MAC 'eno1' [IF1]>:fe:91:14:69:c3:d7:08:00 SRC=192.168.0.1 DST=192.168.0.5 LEN=529 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=37236 DPT=36713 LEN=509 
[   22.877592] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=<MAC 'eno1' [IF1]>:fe:91:14:69:c3:d7:08:00 SRC=192.168.0.1 DST=192.168.0.5 LEN=458 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=32795 DPT=36713 LEN=438 
[   22.879535] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=<MAC 'eno1' [IF1]>:fe:91:14:69:c3:d7:08:00 SRC=192.168.0.1 DST=192.168.0.5 LEN=457 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=51581 DPT=36713 LEN=437 
[   39.860442] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:475b:5375:3dca:1d95 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=829695 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8612 LEN=24 
[   39.860482] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:475b:5375:3dca:1d95 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=1034957 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8610 LEN=24 
[   39.870686] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:475b:5375:3dca:1d95 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=829695 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8612 LEN=24 
[   39.870717] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:475b:5375:3dca:1d95 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=1034957 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8610 LEN=24 
[   64.587740] e1000e: eno1 NIC Link is Down
[   66.053474] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eno1: link is not ready (repeated 2 times)
[   69.082729] e1000e: eno1 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
[   69.082770] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eno1: link becomes ready
[  129.627316] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:fe:91:14:69:c3:d7:08:00 SRC=192.168.0.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=8356 PROTO=2 
[  254.972646] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:fe:91:14:69:c3:d7:08:00 SRC=192.168.0.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=8358 PROTO=2 
[  380.327753] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:fe:91:14:69:c3:d7:08:00 SRC=192.168.0.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=8359 PROTO=2 

########## wireless info END ############
```

**EDIT**

```
$> lshw -C network
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (2) I218-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 05
       serial: 34:97:f6:28:bd:94
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.1-4 ip=192.168.0.5 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:40 memory:fb200000-fb21ffff memory:fb236000-fb236fff ioport:f000(size=32)
```

Comment: In the `lsusb` there doesn't seem to be a wireless device listed? Or am I overlooking something?

Comment: I don't really understand the output of this. But yes, that sounds possible. I have an asus x99 mother, it shoud support wifi. Any ideas how to trouble shoot this?

Comment: I found there are several types of Asus X99's, did not check them all but I think your MoBo should have a Wifi adapter on-board. Verify this in the documentation of your MoBo. If there is an adapter, then go into the BIOS to check the Wifi adapter is Enabled. If it is, start Ubuntu, open a terminal and enter `lshw -C network`. This lists all found hardware in the Network category. Add the command output to your question. If there is no wireless device, the generic drivers of Ubuntu may have failed to recognize the adapter and you may have to obtain one from the Asus website.

Comment: There is nothing in the BIOS I can change that's related to wireless. I only see the ethernet option that is enabled already.

Comment: There is no wireless adapter.

Comment: so there is an issue with the build then? The MoBo has a Wireless adapter.

Comment: If the Mobo has a wireless it is either not working/somehow switched off or Ubuntu can not detect it/did not load a driver for it. Does the Mobo have a LED to indicate the status of the wifi? Did the Mobo come with a setup cd with utils that show the status of the Mobo components. Booting the Live USB does that show wifi as network?

Comment: @WillemK I'll check if everything is correctly plugged and answer the question if this was the isse. Thanks for your input.